# agm-snazzy-info-window displays at random positions

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps, agm

I'm working with

```
"@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
"@agm/snazzy-info-window": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
"agm-direction": "^0.8.6",
"snazzy-info-window": "^1.1.1"
```

And I'm trying to display agm-snazzy-info-window, on marker click.

[my stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo-bda7t4?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

But it's acting weird. The info-window isn't displaying above the marker.

[problem.gif](https://im7.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-7-f1e60956fae0.gif)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Workaround until this [issue](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/1875) is fixed**

Add this to your stylesheet as style.css

`@import '../node_modules/snazzy-info-window/dist/snazzy-info-window.css';`